# Signature for function returning a function pointer

Tags: c++, function, pointers, return

I know in many cases it's best not to ask why, but this function signature makes no sense to me. I know we're supposed to use typedefs, but I wanted to see if I could understand how to do it without:

```
bool(*fn)(std::string&);    // This is function pointer
void funcTakingFunc1(bool(*)(std::string&)) { } // This works for function arguments
bool(*)(std::string&) funcReturningFunc() {}    // Trying the same as return type, doesn't work

bool(*funcReturningFunc2(std::string&))() {}        // This is what I found on another SO question
```

The last one I think is right, it makes no sense to me and the function name and the arguments for the 'return function' are switched around left to right. Is there any explanation for this?

Specifically I'm trying to make a function that takes an `std::string&`, and returns a function pointer to a `bool (*)(std::string&)`, and this doesn't work:

```
bool (*getConsoleCmdByName)(std::string&)(std::string& cmd);
```

Edit: It turns out this is correct, I think:

```
bool (*getConsoleCmdByName(std::string&))(std::string& cmd);
```

Jarod suggested:

```
auto getConsoleCmdByName(std::string&) -> bool (*)(std::string&)
```

As a possibility, that seems clear enough for me.

Comment: `bool (*getConsoleCmdByName)(std::string&)(std::string& cmd);` -> `bool (*getConsoleCmdByName(std::string&))(std::string& cmd);` [Read about the spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html). Then forget it and use type aliases.

Comment: You may use that syntax too (since C++11) `auto getConsoleCmdByName(std::string&) -> bool (*)(std::string&)` (as simple that using typedef IMO).

Comment: Also, prefer not to hide pointer semantics behind an alias, even for functions. Define the function type alias `using func_type = bool(std::string&);` and pass pointers to that `func_type * fptr = ...;`

Comment: Ahhh, I used to hate trailing return types.

Comment: BTW, you should probably want to pass **const** reference instead of non const reference.

Comment: Yes, but can you read this function declaration while standing on your head, holding your right foot with your left hand, drawing a reproduction of Vermeer's *Girl with a pearl ring* with your right hand, and reciting *The Canterbury Tales* from memory, all at the same time? Makes perfect sense too.

Comment: It's so bad not even the compiler understands. When I used that Visual Studio thought I wanted to return a bool instead of a function that returns a bool.

Answer (score 4):

For this purposes and easier understanding complicated expressions exists [Clockwise/spiral](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) rule

```
     +---------------------------------+
     |                                 |
     |       +----------+              |
     |       ^          |              |
bool(*funcReturningFunc2(std::string&))() {}
^    ^                  |              |
|    +------------------+              |
|                                      |
+--------------------------------------+
```

You may ask, what is *funcReturningFunc2*?

- funcReturningFunc2 is a function passing an reference to a string
- funcReturningFunc2 is a function passing an reference to a string returning pointer to
- funcReturningFunc2 is a function passing an reference to a string returning pointer to function passing nothing and returning
- funcReturningFunc2 is a function passing an reference to a string returning pointer to function passing nothing and returning `bool`

Answer (score 0):

Old school pointer-to-function declarations are notoriously difficult to read.

C++11 Provided the standard library with some type-support tools which can be used to simplify complex declarations, *e.g.*:

```
using ret_t = std::add_pointer_t<bool(std::string&)>;
using func_ptr_t = std::add_pointer_t<ret_t(std::string&)>;
```